# What's the correct word to describe spontanous software closure after being stuck?

Tags: word-request

What's the way to describe the following thing?

I use Office Word software, and once it was stuck and wasn't responsive and then (I'm looking for the correct word here: closed, failed, crashed etc.).

Comment: I think "crashed" is common for that. It's more dramatic than "closed" or "failed".

Comment: It doesn't quite fit this scenario, but a common crash trope for Windows OS is the Blue Screen of Death -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_screen_of_death

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common word to describe this is *[crash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crash_(computing))*.  It describes the exit of a program resulting from an error, sometimes after a prolonged period of the computer/program being [frozen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hang_(computing)).